# Problems building Image slideshow with sliding transition using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, filtering, overlay, slideshow

I'm trying to create image slideshow with slide transition using ffmpeg and the following command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img1.jpg -loop 1 -i img2.jpg -loop 1 -i img3.jpg ^
-filter_complex ^
"nullsrc=size=800x600[v0]; ^
[0:v]trim=duration=5,scale=800x600,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; ^
[1:v]trim=duration=5,scale=800x600,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; ^
[2:v]trim=duration=5,scale=800x600,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3]; ^
[v0][v1]overlay=x='min(-w+(t*w/0.5)\,0)':shortest=1[vv0]; ^
[v1][v2]overlay=x='min(-w+(t*w/0.5)\,0)':shortest=1[vv1]; ^
[v2][v3]overlay=x='min(-w+(t*w/0.5)\,0)':shortest=1[vv2]; ^
[vv0][vv1][vv2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0 [video]" -map "[video]" output.mp4
```

I want every image to slide in from left for 0.5 seconds and stay for further 4.5 seconds, before it's being overlapped by the next one and so on.

First problem is that it takes 2-3 minutes to build video with just 3 images and I want to add more images which will result in extremely long build time.

Second problem is that video should be 15 seconds long, but it's only 8 as first image is shown for 5 seconds, second is shown for 2 and the last one just for 1 second.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An input pad generated inside a filter complex can be used only once. So, you should split those streams which will be reused.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img1.jpg -loop 1 -i img2.jpg -loop 1 -i img3.jpg ^
-filter_complex ^
"nullsrc=size=800x600[v0]; ^
[0:v]trim=duration=5,scale=800x600,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split[v1a][v1b]; ^
[1:v]trim=duration=5,scale=800x600,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split[v2a][v2b]; ^
[2:v]trim=duration=5,scale=800x600,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3]; ^
[v0][v1a]overlay=x='min(-w+(t*w/0.5)\,0)':shortest=1[vv0]; ^
[v1b][v2a]overlay=x='min(-w+(t*w/0.5)\,0)':shortest=1[vv1]; ^
[v2b][v3]overlay=x='min(-w+(t*w/0.5)\,0)':shortest=1[vv2]; ^
[vv0][vv1][vv2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0 [video]" -map "[video]" output.mp4
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried what you suggest and video is now 12 seconds as the last scene is only 2 seconds long. Build time is the same.

Comment: Which ffmpeg version and platform?

Comment: Version you can see in the snapshot - https://monosnap.com/file/y2attd8Jz2V9tQB8XwfikUqZWiMff5 . I'm running Windows 10 Pro x64

Comment: hmm, I now tried on Amazon Linux with ffmpeg built from source and it took 15 seconds. May be it's the binaries/system that I'm using.

Comment: Depends on the original image resolutions. I use binaries from the same source on Win 7 x64 and it took 3 seconds when working with 800x600 JPGs. Video is full 15 seconds. Show the console output for your command. Add `-report` to create a logfile.

Comment: Report is here - https://monosnap.com/file/aPiSdOSC6AHveoUn7PTsx4UjBzp9QR. As you can see in the report, I'm actually using 792x612 resolution with images loaded through the network.

Comment: As per the report, full 15 seconds video is generated: `Output stream #0:0 (video): 376 frames encoded; 376 packets muxed (250085 bytes)`. At 25 fps, that's 15 seconds. Check the output with multiple players.  The time for taken for encode is long because you're fetching from a URL and FFmpeg does not realize that it's only 1 image. It thinks it's an image stream and requests the next frame over HTTPS, and that takes a lot of time. Try with locally stored images or you should fetch the image once and then use the loop filter.

Comment: you're right - after prefetching the images, video now takes just a few seconds to build. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Mulvya, I copied your script and changed file name with `in1.png`, `in2.png` and `in3.png`. rest keeping same. It gives error as `Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 800x600, SAR 6:5) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (800x600, SAR 1:1)`